# Determine the interface which was used for booting via PXE

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, pxe

I have a linux machine which was booted via PXE.
Can I determine the network interface which was used for booting?

Answer (score 6):

If assume you're using PXELINUX.

There's a flag `IPAPPEND`; if you set it to `2`, it should cause PXELINUX to append a parameter `BOOTIF=<hardware-address-of-boot-interface>` to your kernel command line. Then you've got the MAC address, which you can use to identify the used interface.

http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/SYSLINUX#IPAPPEND_flag_val_.5BPXELINUX_only.5D

Answer (score 0):

I have used PXELINUX with `IPAPPEND=2` for years. But I recently had to switch to EFI PXE boot, where most people seem to prefer GRUB to PXELINUX.

The GRUB EFI PXE bootloader defines a `$net_default_mac` variable that contains the MAC address of the boot interface. You can use this to add the MAC address to your kernel command line, but it differs from the PXELINUX `IPAPPEND=2` value in two ways:

1. It does not include the hardware type prefix byte (`01` = Ethernet)
2. It uses colons to separate octets instead of dashes (e.g. `ba:98:76:54:32:10` instead of `01-ba-98-76-54-32-10`)

We have some scripts that expect the PXELINUX `BOOTIF` format, so I wanted to replicate that in the GRUB configuration.

Unfortunately, GRUB's text manipulation functions seem to be nearly non-existent. I would up using the [regexp](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/regexp.html) command like so:

```
set dd="[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]"

regexp --set 1:o1 --set 2:o2 --set 3:o3 --set 4:o4 --set 5:o5 --set 6:o6 \
    ($dd):($dd):($dd):($dd):($dd):($dd) \
    $net_default_mac

set hwaddr="01-$o1-$o2-$o3-$o4-$o5-$o6"

menuentry  'My Linux' --class fedora --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
   linuxefi my-kernel-image BOOTIF=$hwaddr
   initrdefi my-initramfs.img
}
```